# AngularJS: Filtering and Uniques with multi level JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have a dataset that is displayed in a table. Each object has a child object of Locations, that also have a child object of Region and Sites, which is an array.

I'm having trouble with 2 issues:

First, in my view to display the Sites data (which is the 'State' value), I'm getting duplicates. I'm trying to use the 'unique' filter to show only unique State values, but it's not working.

Second, I'm wanting to use the select lists with these data elements of Region, State/Country/Province and City to act as a filtering mechanism. That's not working either.

See Plunkr for working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/p0ImqB?p=preview

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['angular.filter']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $anchorScroll, $location, $http) {

 $scope.cart = [];

 $scope.addToCart = function(index) {
  $scope.cart.push(index);

  $scope.cartCount = $scope.cart.length;
 }



 $scope.activeRow = function(index) {
  $scope.selectedRow = index;

  $location.hash();
  $anchorScroll('anchor-' + index);

 }


 $scope.gotoAnchor = function(x) {
  var newHash = 'anchor' + x;


 }
    
        // GET data
        $scope.dataObject = data.List;
        $scope.locationObject = data.Locations;


});
```

```css
body{background:#eee;}
div.cart{display:block;height:70px;background:silver;margin-left:20px;width:200px;padding:5px 10px;margin-bottom:20px;margin-top:20px;}
.cart h1{color:#fff;line-height:20px;}
.item-list-wrapper{height:400px;width:90%;border:1px solid #ddd;overflow-y:scroll;margin-left:20px;}
.item-list-wrapper table td{padding:10px;vertical-align:middle;margin-bottom:10px;font-size:12px;}
.item-list{height:auto;width:100%;margin-bottom:10px;box-shadow:0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);border:1px solid #fff;background:#efefe4;}
.col-num{width:100px;}
.col-compound{width:80px;}
.filters{width:300px;clear:both;margin-left:20px;}
.filters select{display:inline-block;}
.region{font-weight:bolder;}
.state{font-weight:normal;}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="plunker">

      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
        <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="angular-ui.min.css" />
        
        <script>
        document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
      </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.4.7"></script>
        <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular-messages.js"></script>
        <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@*" data-semver="0.13.3" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.1/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.7/angular-filter.min.js"></script>
        <script src="angular-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
        <script src="http://zbl.me/test/103015.js"></script>

      </head>

      <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div ng-view=""></div>
        
  <div class="filters">
        <h2>Filter results</h2>
        
        <select name="selectRegion" class="form-control" ng-model="selectRegion" ng-change="europeSelected()" ng-options="location as location.Region for location in locationObject | orderBy: location.Region:reverse">
         <option value="">Select Region</option>
        </select>
        
        <select name="selectState" class="form-control" ng-disabled="!selectRegion" ng-model="selectState" ng-options="state as state.StateName for state in selectRegion.States">
         <option value="">Select State/Province/Country</option>
        </select>
        
        <select name="selectCity" class="form-control" ng-disabled="!selectState" ng-model="selectCity" ng-options="city as city.CityName for city in selectState.Cities">
         <option value="">Select City</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      
      <div class="cart">
        <h1>Cart: {{cartCount}}</h1></div>
     <div class="item-list-wrapper">
      <table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
       <tr ng-repeat="data in dataObject | filterBy: ['location.Region']: selectRegion | filterBy: ['state.StateName']: selectState | filterBy: ['city.CityName']: selectCity" ng-click="activeRow($index)">
       <td class="column">{{data.Phase}}</td>
       <td class="column col-num">{{data.Number}}</td>
       <td class="column col-compound">{{data.Item}}</td>
       <td>
                <span ng-repeat="location in data.Locations track by $index" class="region">{{ location.Region}}: 
          <span ng-repeat="sites in location.Sites track by $index" class="state">
           <span ng-repeat="item in sites.State track by $index | unique: 'item' ">{{item}}</span>
           </span>
        </span>
       </td>
       <td><a href="" ng-click="addToCart()">Add</a></td>
      </tr>
      </table>
     </div>
      </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the HTML, you were repeating in `sites.State` but there is not any array there, it's only a string.

Changing the `item-list-wrapper` to this one in the HTML will solve the problem:

```
 <div class="item-list-wrapper">
     <table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
        <tr ng-repeat="data in dataObject | filterBy: ['location.Region']: selectRegion | filterBy: ['state.StateName']: selectState | filterBy: ['city.CityName']: selectCity" ng-click="activeRow($index)">
            <td class="column">{{data.Phase}}</td>
            <td class="column col-num">{{data.Number}}</td>
            <td class="column col-compound">{{data.Compound}}</td>
            <td>
        <span ng-repeat="location in data.Locations track by $index" class="region">{{ location.Region}}: 
                <span ng-repeat="site in location.Sites | unique: 'State'" class="state">{{site.State}}
                    </span>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td><a href="" ng-click="addToCart()">Add</a></td>
        </tr>
     </table>
 </div>
```

Here´s the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/VmLjZmgLtDuds5CM7lKM?p=preview

Regarding the second problem with the filters, I'd solve it with the following custom filters:

```
app.filter('itemFilter', function() {
 return function(input,region,state) {
    if (!region)
      return input;
    return input.filter(function (x) {
      return x.Locations.some(function (y) {
        if (!state)
          return y.Region == region.Region;
        else
          return y.Sites.some(function (z) {
            return z.State == state.StateName;
          });
      });
    });
  };
});

app.filter('regionFilter', function() {
  return function(input,region,state) {
    if (!region)
      return input;
    return input.filter(function(y) {
      if (!state)
        return y.Region == region.Region;
      else
        return y.Sites.some(function (z) {
          return z.State == state.StateName;
        });
    });
  };
});
```

You can use them in the code as shown below:

```
 <div class="item-list-wrapper">
     <table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
        <tr ng-repeat="data in dataObject | itemFilter:selectRegion:selectState" ng-click="activeRow($index)">
            <td class="column">{{data.Phase}}</td>
            <td class="column col-num">{{data.Number}}</td>
            <td class="column col-compound">{{data.Compound}}</td>
            <td>
        <span ng-repeat="location in data.Locations | regionFilter:selectRegion:selectState" class="region">{{ location.Region}}: 
                <span ng-repeat="site in location.Sites | unique: 'State' | filter: { State: selectState.StateName }" class="state">{{site.State}}
                    </span>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td><a href="" ng-click="addToCart()">Add</a></td>
        </tr>
     </table>
 </div>
```

Here's the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/liWYtMIC1rDktmBYQtjo?p=preview

Comment: That handles the dupes, but what about the filtering?

Comment: Hi SerpicoLugNut, I did not notice there was another problem, those filterings are kind of complicated because you don't want to show an item that contains the region but it does not contain the state so I used custom filters to make sure the output is consistent with both filters. I did not used City because it was not used in the output but you can add it easily passing `selectedCity` to the filter and adding another level to the existing filters and a new custom filter to the State loop in the HTML.